# php simple html parser, trouble getting table data

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

[image: I want to download the table that starts with this table data]

I have not been able to parse the data in this table, Daily Prices. Any suggestions?

This is the website with the table I want to download,
https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/Zbz20/price-history/historical

```
$website = 'https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/Zbz20/price-history/historical';
$html = file_get_html($website);

foreach($html->find('div[data-ng-bind="cell"]') as $element){
      pa($element);
      echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';   
}
```

```
I have also used this without success. 

    foreach($html->find('td div span span span') as $esData){
    pa($esData);
    echo $esData->plaintext. '<br>';  
    }

Thanks!
```

Comment: The `ngIf` comments indicate that the page is rendered by Angular. The data will not be in the HTML source code

Comment: Viewing the network tab in developer tools in the browser you can find the api call that returns the json data that populates in the html via angular. You should be able to snag the data from there - may have to set headers for referrer etc to mimic the website.

Comment: Thanks all, I will investigate. Alternatively, I would be happy to import from csv into sql from the "Download" link. Any tips about getting that direct link so I can code that into php? Thanks, thanks, thanks!

Comment: The download button appears to work by sending data loaded from the json get api to the server to initiate a download. Hitting up the api endpoint with the appropriate parameters and headers to mimic a browser seems the best bet. https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/historical/get